# Hostname resolves, domain does not

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I just finished setting up WHM on a new server running CentOS 6. My hostname is set as **n.env.ms**. If I go to the hostname I get the standard cPanel "Default Homepage". If I try to go to **env.ms** I get webpage is not available.

DNS Zone records for n.env.ms and env.ms look nearly identical aside from env.ms having extra fields like "default_domainkey" and "cpanel".

This is the domain's [**intoDNS report**](http://www.intodns.com/env.ms)

Clearly something is wrong on the server. The IP addresses intoDNS reports are correct so it's not something on the registrar. Port 53 (TCP/UDP) is open.

This is a portion the zone file for the domain:

```
env.ms. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.env.ms.
env.ms. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.env.ms.

env.ms. 14400   IN  A   50.62.213.152
```

ns1 and ns2 zone details:

```
ns1.env.ms. 14400   IN  A   50.62.213.152
localhost   14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
ns1.env.ms. 14400   IN  MX  0   ns1.env.ms.


ns2.env.ms. 14400   IN  A   50.63.175.168
localhost   14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
ns2.env.ms. 14400   IN  MX  0   ns2.env.ms.
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll be no help with cpanel, but the nameservers simply do not believe they are responsible for env.ms.

I'm not exactly following with regard to your zones.. are you creating a new zone for every host?  Again, I don't use cpanel but that's not how it's normally done.  While it will work with a proper configuration you shouldn't be doing that unless you understand why you would be doing that.

ns1 and ns2 should be in the env.ms. zone and that should be the only zone you need.  It should work if you got rid of the other zones besides env.ms.(again, this is for BIND, not cpanel, YMMV) and simply add records to env.ms.:

in env.ms. zone:

```
env.ms. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.env.ms.
env.ms. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.env.ms.
env.ms. 14400   IN  A   50.62.213.152
ns1     14400   IN  A   50.62.213.152
ns2     14400   IN  A   50.63.175.168
```

No separate zones for ns1 or ns2.  Keep it simple.

Comment: You'll have to talk to your provider or a cpanel expert then.  Those aren't separate zones.  If you had to make a zone for every single hostname imagine how many zones a company like Google would have (one per server at a minimum).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your DNS setup:

```
[me@risby ext4]$ dig env.ms. @ns1.env.ms.
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
env.ms.         14400   IN  A   50.62.213.152

[me@risby ext4]$ dig env.ms.
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
env.ms.         14400   IN  A   50.62.213.152

[me@risby ext4]$ dig n.env.ms.
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
n.env.ms.       14400   IN  A   50.62.213.152
```

Something may well be wrong with your **webserver** setup, but your DNS looks fine to me.

I note that, some hours after posting, you attemped to redact the domain from your question, and from the other posted answer; I co-rejected the latter edit and rolled back the former.  I'm slightly sorry for that, but SF is a wiki: it's genuinely pointless to try to remove information **after** you've posted it, and hopefully you can see that knowing the actual domain name is quite important in diagnosing DNS issues.

Comment: For the record, the domain was NOT set up the way it is now when the question was asked.  There were no NS records returned for any env.ms. queries previously.  It does look like it's correct now though.

Answer (score 0):

You actually just need to create a cPanel account from your WHM with env.ms and that should should solve your case. Withought the account you only have a hostname the resolves to its IP.

With the cPanel account, now you have the website. Login to your WHM at https://env.me:2087

- Go Create Account
- Type in the domain env.me
- Generate Password
- Scroll to Create account.

This should be done for you.